# How can I get the same kind of slide show as Photos and Facebook in my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, image

There's already excellent code for browsing and viewing pictures on the iPhone, as shown by apps like Photos and Facebook, and I don't feel like inventing the wheel again. I thought that this functionality would be built into the API, but I'm having a hard time finding it. Am I blind or do Apple really force us to write our own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook gave rise to the [Three20 framework](http://three20.info).

Everything you're looking for is in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try out a UIScrollView with paging enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Or using DMCarousel: https://github.com/brianegan/dmcarousel

Comment: Not sure why I didn't notice this answer until now, but I'm pretty sure that won't work, since it seems to be for the web and not iOS.